# Unable to load the truck to deliver the product from a warehouse storage

Tags: anylogic

**Description of a Model**: Developing a WareHouse Model, which takes Pallets from a Truck and unloads it by unloaders and places them at someplace then the Transferer will pick that pallet and then put it on a conveyor. At the end of the Conveyor, the Forklifters will pick and place it in a storage area. After a delay then Forklifters will Retrieve it and place it at some point then loaders will pick that up and load it to a RetailTruck.

As i am new to posting in Stackoverflow and i don't have the required reputation to post it directly images, though i have uploaded the images it has converted into a link, can find it below :
The issue is that ( i want loaders to load the pallets into a RetailTruck from the storage system). The Source is generating Orders passing through SelectOutput and then going directly to the sink instead to process the orders.

```
[Console 1][1]
[Console 2][2]
[SupplyOrders][3]
[managingOrders][4]
[queue][5]
[combine-CollectionOrderPallet][6]
[seize][7]
[moveTo][8]
[release][9]
[pallet][10]
[Palletcollection][11]
[pallet function][12]


   https://i.stack.imgur.com/N5AW0.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2WZ6.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/El5R0.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/WuhwM.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/mlRVB.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/rf01T.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/VPjtK.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwCdv.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/NMauO.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/3vyLF.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/23wBF.png
   https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah0gN.png
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Actually, i have attached the link of the screenshots with .Png format in a code section  to the problem

Comment: Hey, welcome to SOF. You don't seem to get replies because the question is really not clear and simple. Here are some tips, maybe rewrite it and focus to the key issue, show what you already tried and make those links clickable (in short: make our lives as easy as possible): https://www.benjamin-schumann.com/blog/2021/4/1/how-to-win-at-anylogic-on-stackoverflow

Comment: Sorry, to describe it in a simple way: In a warehouse, the unloading, processing of the pallets, storage, and retrieving part is completed and working but getting error at the time of loading to the retail truck to delivery of the product.

Comment: previously, the links were actually not redirecting because it has attached with square brackets with value in it[ ], which represent the serial number ex: 1,2,3,4 ...